# fashion_mnist.load_data() fails do to force connection closed by remote

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to go through the tensorflow tutorial which requires me to execture the line

```
fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

in my code to download the data set. In the middle of the download I get the following error.

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

How can I prevent the host from closing the connection.

File Being Executed

```
import _thread
import time
import chess

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist


class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_images.shape
```

Output I Get

```
1.12.0
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz

8192/5148 [===============================================] - 0s 0us/step
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

   8192/4422102 [..............................] - ETA: 4s
  57344/4422102 [..............................] - ETA: 5s
 147456/4422102 [>.............................] - ETA: 3s
 278528/4422102 [>.............................] - ETA: 2s
 376832/4422102 [=>............................] - ETA: 2s
 385024/4422102 [=>............................] - ETA: 3s
 393216/4422102 [=>..........


... [more lines] ... 

   ====>........................] - ETA: 42:25
 5758976/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 42:32
 5767168/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 42:39
 5775360/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 42:46
 5783552/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 42:54
 5791744/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 43:09
 5799936/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 43:18
 5808128/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 43:26
 5816320/26421880 [=====>........................] - ETA: 43:34Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PiChess\Core\hello - Copy.py", line 20, in <module>
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\datasets\fashion_mnist.py", line 52, in load_data
    paths.append(get_file(fname, origin=base + fname, cache_subdir=dirname))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 249, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 277, in urlretrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Did you try downloading the dataset multiple times?

Comment: Yes. This error has happened on every attempt of every type of data set.